# Java Duplicate Local variable

Tags: java

It says "Duplicate Local Variable v"

the 10th line is highlighted

What do I change?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class SimpleCalcu
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

    int n1,n2;
    String operation;
    char v;
    Scanner v = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please Enter The First Number");
    n1 = v.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter The Second Number");
    n2 = v.nextInt();

    System.out.println("Please Enter The Operation");
    operation = v.next();

    if (operation.equals("+"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 + n2));
    }
    else if (operation.equals("-"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 - n2));
    }       
    else if (operation.equals("*"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 * n2));
    }   
    else if (operation.equals("/"))
    {
        System.out.println("Your Answer is "+(n1 / n2));
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: You cannot have two local variables with same name; here `v` is declared as a `char` and also `Scanner`

Comment: 'ASAP'? Please read our FAQ :http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: In all seriousness, what did you not understand from the error message? It tells you exactly what the problem is.

Answer (score 2):

remove

```
char v;
```

since you never use it, and it has the same name as `Scanner v`.

Answer (score 1):

The error is obvious and telling you exactly what the problem is. You have a duplicate variable `v`.

One is a `char` and the other is a `Scanner`.

Pick which one you want to be `v` and change the other.

Answer (score 1):

Try to remove this line:

```
 char v;
```

Because you have the name of `Scanner v`,or if you want to use it you can change his name in ex: `char v1;`

Comment: I removed the "char v;" and it says "v is never closed" Please help me :)

Comment: @Captain Try to add this v.close()  in the end of your code

Comment: @Captain I tested now but doesn't give this error, can you send me the error

Comment: I got it Tysm for your help I added v.close()

Comment: @Captain feel free, if you want to accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

one name is locally for one variable: v is for two variable => change one of them

other advice: use significant names: Scanner scan, for example, char c, etc.